# SQL how to structure a database where elements frequently change values

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I am trying to create a database for a sport which has many leagues and within those leagues there are many teams which contain players that frequently change leagues and teams.

I would like to know the best way to go about structuring a database so that I can keep track of when a player changes teams as well as knowing which teams they have been on and when.

Btw I am very new to SQL so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is consider the core elements. You said Leagues, teams and players and you also want some means of logging a player changing teams and I'd guess also teams changing leagues.

So that could be 5 tables -

- a league table
- a team table
- a player table
- a history (including current) of what league a team is in
- a history of what team (including current) a player is in (and therefore has been in)

So I believe the following may be along the lines of a suitable structure (populates with some testing the data as well) :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS player;
DROP TABLE If EXISTS team;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS leauge;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS team_league_history;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS player_team_history;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS league (league_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, league_name TEXT);
-- Add some leauges
INSERT INTO league (league_name) VALUES
    ('1st Division'),('2nd Division'),('3rd Division'),('4th Division');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS team (team_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, team_name TEXT);
-- Add some teams
INSERT INTO team (team_name) VALUES
    ('Team A'),('Team B'),('Team C'),('Team D'),('Team E'),('Team F'),('Team G'),('Team H'),('Team I'),('Team J'),('Team K')
;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS player (player_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, player_name);
-- Add some players
INSERT INTO player (player_name) VALUES
    ('P0'),('P1'),('P2'),('P3'),('P4'),('P5'),('P6'),('P7'),('P8'),('P9'),
    ('P10'),('P11'),('P12'),('P13'),('P14'),('P15'),('P16'),('P17'),('P18'),('P19'),
    ('P20'),('P21'),('P22'),('P23'),('P24'),('P25'),('P26'),('P27'),('P28'),('P29'),
    ('P30'),('P31'),('P32'),('P33'),('P34'),('P35'),('P36'),('P37'),('P38'),('P39'),
    ('P40'),('P41'),('P42'),('P43'),('P44'),('P45'),('P46'),('P47'),('P48'),('P49')
;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS team_league_history (
    tlh_team_reference INTEGER, 
    tlh_league_reference INTEGER, 
    tlh_from_date TEXT DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE, 
    tlh_to_date TEXT DEFAULT '3000-12-31'
);
-- Add current standings
INSERT INTO team_league_history (tlh_team_reference,tlh_league_reference) VALUES 
    (6,3), -- Team F in 3rd Div
    (1,4), -- Team A in 4th div
    (2,1),(3,1),(11,1),
  (4,2),(7,2),(9,2),
    (5,3),(10,3),
    (8,4)
;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS player_team_history (
    pth_player_reference INTEGER, 
    pth_team_reference INTEGER, 
    pth_from_date TEXT DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE, 
    pth_to_date TEXT DEFAULT '3000-12-31'
);
-- Add current team composition
INSERT INTO player_team_history (pth_player_reference, pth_team_reference) VALUES
    (1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,1),(5,1),(6,1),(7,2),(8,2),(9,2),(10,2),
        (11,3),(12,3),(13,3),(14,3),(15,4),(16,4),(17,4),(18,4),(19,4),(20,4),
        (21,5),(22,5),(23,5),(24,5),(25,5),(26,6),(27,6),(28,6),(29,6),(30,6),
        (31,7),(32,7),(33,7),(34,7),(35,7),(36,8),(37,8),(38,8),(39,8),(40,8),
        (41,9),(42,9),(43,9),(44,9),(45,9),(46,10),(47,10),(48,11),(49,11),(50,11)
;
```

*may be more to come in the way of example uses of the above*

### Example based upon the above :-

#### Teams in each League

```
--List Teams in each League
SELECT league_name AS Leauge, group_concat(team_name) AS Teams
FROM team_league_history 
    JOIN league ON tlh_league_reference = league_id
    JOIN team ON tlh_team_reference = team_id
GROUP BY league_id
;
```

- Results in
  [image]

#### Players in Teams

```
-- Players in Teams
SELECT team_name AS Team, group_concat(player_name) AS Players
FROM player_team_history
    JOIN team ON pth_team_reference = team_id
    JOIN player ON pth_player_reference = player_id
GROUP BY team_name
;
```

- Results in 
  [image]

#### Players in teams with with league

```
-- Players in Teams and Leauge
SELECT team_name AS Team, 
group_concat(player_name) AS Players, 
 (
        SELECT league_name 
        FROM team_league_history 
            JOIN league ON tlh_league_reference = league_id
        WHERE tlh_team_reference = team_id
    )AS League
FROM player_team_history
    JOIN team ON pth_team_reference = team_id
    JOIN player ON pth_player_reference = player_id
GROUP BY team_name
ORDER BY league, team
;
```

- Results in
[image]

The perhaps consider :-

```
-- Making changes
-- 1 Change a Team name
UPDATE team SET team_name = 'My changed name' WHERE team_name = 'Team B';

-- Adjust some League compositions
-- DROP Team B and K down to Div 2
UPDATE team_league_history SET tlh_league_reference = 2 WHERE tlh_team_reference = 2 or tlh_team_reference = 11;
UPDATE team_league_history SET tlh_league_reference = 1 WHERE tlh_team_reference = 4 or tlh_team_reference = 9;

-- Move some players between teams (not history though)
-- Hopefully players P35-37 (id's 36-38) moved to team A
UPDATE player_team_history SET pth_team_reference = 1 WHERE pth_player_reference > 35 AND pth_player_reference < 39;
```

The Player, Team, League would then be :-

[image]

#### History

The above demonstrations are all changes to the current (cheated using DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE when inserting and DEFAULT 3000-12-31).

but history (both tables) would/could have many rows per player (pth) or team (lth) with the from_date-to_date covering the period that the situation existed (team was in league, player was in a team). The absence of a row covering a period would indicate non-existence (team broke up/disbanded, player in hospital/jail or something, although if such events could themselves potentially have a history row along with an event indicator (if that's the right term) table).

#### Note

- the above has been manipulated based upon numeric references e.g. P25 equates to player_id 26 *(names were selected for convenience)*, which us mere mortals tend to get confused with. Typically though the user(s) would be using an graphical interface an be oblivious to the fact that Joe Bloggs is id x, they just select Joe Bloggs.

Comment: Could you clarify how the player_team_history table would look if a player were to leave a specific team but return at a later time? Would I simply create a new row or would this structure not work for such an edge case? Thank you for the detail in your answer btw.

Comment: @JackTilley I believe that would be a **no row** for that duration so prior history row would be 2000-2010, next row would be 2015-3000 so player not in a team between 2011 and 2014 (just years used for simplicity).

Answer (score 0):

[image: This should give you a good start]

You should also check out temporal tables - they would give you the ability to keep historical information about a players relationship with a given team at any moment in time.

Comment: Temporal Table information here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Would you happen to know of any way I could make this work on sqlite?

Comment: You would have to manage the historic information yourself, that is you would have tables that are structured the same as your primary table with additional fields for active start and active ends - you could then insert into the history table the output of an update. If you are very new to SQL and all of this don't sweat it, mastering database development takes years, take your time and learn.